# Inconsistent stack height 1 !=2

Tags: java, jvm, stack, jasmin

so I'm trying to make a simple for loop in Jasmin that prints out hello world everytime it goes through the loop. The problem is whenever I try to increment it by adding one I get this error that says, 
"Error: Unable to initialize main class test
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: test, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V)
Inconsistent stack height 1 != 2"
It works when I'm not trying to add one, but not sure why it doesn't when I put it back in. Any help would be appreciated!

```
.class public test
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
   aload_0
   invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
   return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   .limit stack 5

   ldc 15
   ldc 1
startLoop:
   iflt endLoop
   getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   ldc "hello world"
   invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   ldc 1
   iadd
   goto startLoop
endLoop:
   return
.end method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code ends up with a different stack height depending on whether you go to `endLoop` immediately on the first iteration (the verifier doesn't check or see that your value is never smaller than zero) or whether you have gone through the loop.

Keep in mind that `iflt` compares the top of the stack with zero and if it is less than zero , it goes to `endLoop`. In the process, it removes the value from the top of the stack.

After your first `iflt`, it removed the value `1` from the top of the stack. Then it adds `1` to `15`, leaving the value `16` on the stack.

The next `iflt` pops the value `16` from the stack - on he next iteration the `iadd` would fail because there is only one value on the stack (`1`) and `iadd` needs two.

As a solution, you probably want to use `if_icmpge` to check if your counter is greater than 15,
And for every comparison, you first want to `dup` your counter and then push the constant `15` on the stack.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for taking the time to answer!